# Prove that: $\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{n \log n}}\rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$be i.i.d with density $$f(x)=\begin{cases}|x|^{-3} \text{ if |x|>1}\\0\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ 
Prove that: 
$\frac{\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sqrt{n \log n}}\rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution.

I know in this one, I need to use Lindeberg-Feller thm; however, is the $X_{n,i}$ is $\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{n \log n}}$. It seems not. Any hints or solutions are welcome.

Comment: What is the problem you meet when trying to apply Lindeberg-Feller, exactly (the sentence with "however" and "It seems not" is noninformative)?

Comment: @Did I have no idea what you are talking about after "exactly".

Comment: @Did I don't know your intention or purpose. Focus on my words is not useful for this question.

Comment: Again: What is the problem you meet when trying to apply Lindeberg-Feller? (Not answering the first time I asked is an information in itself, the info that you do not want to add personal input.)

Comment: @Did Like I said, if I want to apply L-F, I need to have a $X_{n,i}$ satisfying those properties in the thm. I don't know whether the $X_{n,i}$ here is just $\frac{X_i}{\sqrt{n \log n}}$.

Comment: And if you define $X_{n,i}=X_i/\sqrt{n\log n}$, do these random variables $X_{n,i}$ satisfy the required properties for LF to apply, or not? *We still do not know* (!).

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment,
not a proof.

Feller, vol. II,
page 260, section VIII.4,
 central limit theorem,
has this example:

Example. (a) Central limit theorem with infinite variances. It is of
methodological interest to note that the proof of theorem 1 applies without
change to certain distributions without variance, provided appropriate
norming constants are chosen.

For example, if the $X_k$ have a density such
that 
$f(x) = 2 |x|^{-3} \log |x|
$
 for $|x| \ge 1$
 and 
$f(x) = 0$ for $|x| \le 1
$
then
$\dfrac{X_1 + ... +X_n}{\sqrt{2n} \log n}$
 has a normal limit distribution.

Perhaps a modification
of this result
can give you what you want.

Note:
I have always felt that
I understood most of
Feller's volume I,
but volume II was generally
over my head.
However,
I somehow remembered something
about this example
and was able to find it.